# Autocomplete Address Fill in Django CreateView

Tags: django

Ok so I need some help. I am trying to have the address field from my CreateView form auto populate with the Places API result. So I see 2 options:

1. Override the address field in the CreateView. Use the address input for Places API as the input into the address field for my model.
2. Autocomplete the address field in the form, from the output of the address input (Places API lookup).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I have tried multiple different options and cant seem to get it to actually work correctly.

Thanks.

autocomple.html

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;

var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
  // geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById('autocomplete'), {types: ['geocode']});

  // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
  // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
  autocomplete.setFields(['address_component']);

  // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
  // address fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  console.log(place)

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details,
  // and then fill-in the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}


// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle(
          {center: geolocation, radius: position.coords.accuracy});
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

views.py

```
class PropertyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Property
    fields = ['address', 'postal_code', 'price',
              'details', 'sales_status', 'property_type']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

detail.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

      {% block content%}
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-2">
          <div class="card-body p-0">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="p-5">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">New Property</h1>
                  </div>
                    <form method="POST">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Address: </label>
                          <div id="locationField">
                              <input id="autocomplete"
                                 placeholder="Enter your address"
                                 onFocus="geolocate()"
                                 type="text"
                                 name="full_address"
                              class="form-control"
                              />
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <fieldset class="form-group">
                          {{ form|crispy }}
                      </fieldset>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block"" type="submit">Add Property</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  <hr>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        {% include 'properties_app/autocomplete.html' %}
```

Comment: For auto completion you can use https://select2.org/.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your current code? What isn't working? It's a lot of code to read and I'd like not to "guess" what's wrong with it. Tell us what behaviour you're seeing, any errors you see in your browser dev tools (js errors), or in your django console, etc...

Comment: The autocomplete is not populating the address field in my CreateView form. Sorry for the code, wanted to give full context.

Comment: and what do you see in your javascript console? any errors?

Comment: where are you calling `initAutoComplete()`? If  you never call it, nothing will happen.

Comment: This is the code I pulled off Google website. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. New to all this. Error is console is:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at Tt.fillInAddress`

Which is referencing this line:
`document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;`